# Export YouTube subscribers as text list

Tags: youtube

Is there any way to export all YouTube subscribers as a text list?

Is there any API, or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YouTube Data API provides you the option to retrieve subscribers list
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list

Making an authorized request on this URL you will get a JSON response with your subscribers:

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?part=snippet&mySubscribers=true&key={YOUR_API_KEY}`

Comment: Sounds good. Can you add more information about how to use it? Add an example, please.

Comment: There are different ways of using the API. But most important thing is that you must know about basic web languages. Actually, you will get better help by YouTube API experts on Stackoverflow at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?tags=youtube-api 

and also get started with YouTube API https://developers.google.com/youtube/getting_started

Comment: Accepting. Sorry for late accept. It's the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit late (eight or so years), but I created a [YouTube Subscriptions Exporter](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/youtube-subscriptions-exp/dhpojdmnffaocepmljcdcongdmkjblan) Chrome extension that exports your YouTube subscriptions to a text list (to the clipboard.)

The output is a list of subscriber names, followed by a tab, followed by the subscriber URL. It can be easily pasted into a spreadsheet for further processing. I'm also working on exporting to other formats like OPML (RSS), and a few others.